# Running Project Wonder REST example throws an exception

Tags: java, eclipse, rest

I am trying to reproduce the example from the Wiki tutorial for Project Wonder REST:

community.org/display/WEB/Your+First+Rest+Project#YourFirstRestProject-Addingpostsandauthorswithcurl

I am the point where you add entries in the DB with curl (I couldn't do it, I added them via SQL).

I am trying to run the curl command to retrieve entries and get an error "Empry reply from server". The console reports the following:

```
Request start for URI /cgi-bin/WebObjects/BlogTutorial.woa/ra/blogEntries.json
Headers{accept = ("*/*"); host = ("127.0.0.1:45743"); user-agent = ("curl/7.38.0"); }
[2015-8-14 17:20:19 CEST] <WorkerThread14> <er.rest.routes.ERXRouteRequestHandler>: Exception while handling action named "index" on action class "your.app.rest.controllers.BlogEntryController" :com.webobjects.foundation.NSForwardException [java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException] null:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
_ignoredPackages:: ("com.webobjects", "java.applet", "java.awt", "java.awt.datatransfer", "java.awt.event", "java.awt.image", "java.beans", "java.io", "java.lang", "java.lang.reflect", "java.math", "java.net", "java.rmi", "java.rmi.dgc", "java.rmi.registry", "java.rmi.server", "java.security", "java.security.acl", "java.security.interfaces", "java.sql", "java.text", "java.util", "java.util.zip")
Headers{cache-control = ("private", "no-cache", "no-store", "must-revalidate", "max-age=0"); expires = ("Fri, 14-Aug-2015 15:20:19 GMT"); content-type = ("text/html"); content-length = ("9296"); pragma = ("no-cache"); x-webobjects-loadaverage = ("1"); date = ("Fri, 14-Aug-2015 15:20:19 GMT"); set-cookie = (); }
```

The request start and both Headers messages are mine, through an override of dispatchRequest.

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, before I overrode the method I received in my X-terminal the following html code (I have removed the stack trace and some other info):
  <tr> 
          <td> <b>Error:</b> </td>
          <td"> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr> 
          <td> <b>Reason:</b> </td>
          <td> com.webobjects.appserver.WORequest cannot be cast to er.extensions.appserver.ERXRequest 
          </td>
        </tr>

Comment: I have tracked the error up to WOActionRequestHandler.getActionInstance(Class, Class[], aobj)

Exception is thrown in there, although arguments look OK to me:

Class your.app.rest.controllers.BlogEntriesController

Class[0] com.webobjects.appserver.WORequest

aobj[0] WORequest <com.webobjects.appserver.WORequest httpVersion=HTTP/1.1 headers={accept=[text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8], accept-encoding=[gzip, deflate], accept-language=[en-US,en;q=0.5], connection=[keep-alive], host=[127.0.0.1:30005], <<<<more stuff>>>